# Matplotlib savefig() OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'image.png'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a program that will create a matplotlib chart and save the png file. I've tried using the `savefig()` method ([more info here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)), but it gives me the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'image.png'
```

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
    plt.title("Bar (Spreading of transactions)")
    plt.plot(bar_x, bar_y)
    plt.savefig("image.png")
```

I will later need to save this file in a temporary file and access it using Flask.

Comment: try to replace "image.png" by "./image.png" (or with a full path)

Comment: @tgrandje I replaced it with "./image.png" and it gave me the same error. The full path gave me the following error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'desktop/tradercs50/image.png'"

Comment: Judging by the "Desktop" in your file name, I'm guessing you are on Windows. Try to make a directory where you are sure you are able to write and then use an absolute path, including the drive letter, as suggested above. Something like `"C:/MyDir/MyFile.png"`.

Comment: Oh! And if the forward slashes may be a problem, change them to reverse slashes but add a 'r'  starting the string. Something like ```r"C:\MyDir\MyFile.png".```

Comment: @accdias I'm actually on a Mac...

Comment: It seems that you are in a read only filesystem, so you cannot save an image in there given that is not a read operation. Checkout (this post)[https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable] The post is on Ubuntu but I think will give you another possibility for your problem.

Comment: Some initial steps to try (1) identify the location you are trying to save `image.png` - this should be the current working directory where you are running python from. (2) try creating a file in that location from the terminal (`touch test.txt`). If you still get a read-only error, you know you need to change the permissions of the directory or try saving to a different location. If that works, then (3) try writing to a file in that location from a python interpreter (e.g. `with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write("testing")`). This will tell you if python is able to write to that directory

Comment: Hey everyone! I tried running again and it allowed me to do this. I'm not sure what happened, but it worker now.

Comment: Thank you all for the effort in answering in helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a permission issue. You can give a path where the user you are using has write permission.

You can check the permissions with `ls -l /the/path/of/your/choice`.
To give write permission recursively in this directory `chmod u+w -R /the/path/of/your/choice` 
(`u` for the user who own the directory, `+w` to add write permission and `-R` to recursively do it)

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be a permissions issue, not a python issue. You'll need to change the permissions of the folder you're trying to write to. In a terminal, use chmod:

```sh
chmod -R 777 /absolute/path/to/your/folder
```

If you're not sure what the absolute path is, navigate to your directory (in the terminal using `cd`) and type `pwd`.

OSX usually ships with "Terminal". If you're not sure where to find it press "command"+"spacebar" and type "terminal" in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, savefig() shouldn't be used as a method of your figure ? for example, one of my programs use it as follows :

```
def save(name):
    fig = plt.figure(num=1,figsize=(10,10), clear=True)
    #change axis color to white so they wont appear on the figure
    plt.rcParams['xtick.color'] = 'w'
    plt.rcParams['ytick.color'] = 'w'
    plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'w'
    plt.rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = 'w'
    #display the image on the figure
    plt.imshow(gist_rainbow(map))
    #save the figure
    fig.savefig(name)
```

this way, calling this function like `save("image.png")` will save the image `map` wich is stored under a matrix of floats converted into RGBA thanks to the matplotlib gist_rainbow colormap, but you can just use it to save whatever is displayed on your figure between the declaration of `fig` and the call of the `savefig()` method.
Also, if the file already exist and you want to overwrite it, it may be a question of permissions. In this case, you should try to run `ls -la` command on several files of your filesystem in search of particular restrictions.

Comment: Hey! But `gist_rainbow` is not even from matplotlib. I tried importing it but it doesn't exist. So I'm unsure of what I should do.

Comment: It is, but it's a custom name, you need to do `from matplotlib import cm` then `gist_rainbow = cm.get_cmap(name="gist_rainbow")` (`get_cmap` function return a callable you can assign to a variable with any name) PS: you can learn more about matplotlib colormap [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question